# Login in Azure with Application multi-tenant

Tags: azure, sharepoint, outlook, office365

In Office 365 I have an api registered with "krunal@mydomin.com" credential and I'm creating an API to log in with Office 365 as well as a folder in Office 365.

My question is how can other people with "someone@hisdomin.com" use my API ? As it is now, this does not work.

Is it possible ?

**FYI : Application is multi-tenant = "YES"**

[image]

Is it possible for "**someone@hisdomin.com**" to login and create folder in Office 365 ?

Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Please take some time and edit your question. It is full of typos and grammatical errors. For starters, it is `azure` and not `azury`. Please see this help link: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri : thanks for correcting me for **"Azure"** and its reply helpful

Answer (score 0):

Users that are members of your Office 365 like someone@yourdomain.com are able to access your API.
If you want that someone outside of your organization accesses your API you will need to add this user as an external user in your office 365

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85